# False ValueError with scipy.signal.savgol_filter

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, filtering

I am confused. I have 21 files that have been generated by the same process and I am filtering them all using savitzky-golay filter with the same parameters.
It works normally for some files, but at some point, I receive the `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs`. The problem is, I checked the file and there aren't any infs or NaNs!

```
print "nan", df.isnull().sum()
print "inf", np.isinf(df).sum()
```

gives

```
nan x        0
T          0
std_T      0
sterr_T    0
dtype: int64
inf x        0
T          0
std_T      0
sterr_T    0
dtype: int64
```

So the problem may be in implementation of the filter? Could this result from for example the choice of window length or polyorder relative to the length or step of the data?

Complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-40b33049ef41>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/data/scripts/DailyProfiles_Gradients.py', wdir='D:/data/DFDP2/DFDP2B/DTS/DTS_scripts')

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/data/scripts/DailyProfiles_Gradients.py", line 142, in <module>
    grad = gradient(y, x, scale,PO)

  File "D:/data/scripts/DailyProfiles_Gradients.py", line 76, in Tgradient
    smoothed=savgol_filter(list(x), scale, PO, deriv=1, delta=dy[0])

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_savitzky_golay.py", line 337, in savgol_filter
    coeffs = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv=deriv, delta=delta)

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_savitzky_golay.py", line 140, in savgol_coeffs
    coeffs, _, _, _ = lstsq(A, y)

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 822, in lstsq
    b1 = _asarray_validated(b, check_finite=check_finite)

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 187, in _asarray_validated
    a = toarray(a)

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1033, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

This problem is rather specific to the data and method and I have not been able to produce a minimum reproducible working example. I am not asking for fixing my code, I am just asking for some brainstorming: *What aspects have I not checked yet that might be causing the error? What should the function parameters look like, other than that the window length must be an odd number greater than the polyorder?*

I am grateful for the discussion that has arisen, it helped, eventually.

Comment: there's no way to help you with this without a reproducible example http://sscce.org/

Comment: My apologies, but creating a reproducible example would mean I know HOW to create it, i.e. knowing what causes the error. In which case, I would not need to ask such a question.

Comment: In addition to the "sscce" (or a [minimal, complete and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it would also help us help you if you include the *complete* Python traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  It contains useful information.

Comment: Thanks!  Now, either by adding `print` calls or by using a debugger, figure out what the arguments are to `savgol_filter()`.  That is, what are the values of `x`, `scale`, `PO` and `dy[0]` that trigger the error?

Comment: FWIW, I can trigger the same error by making `delta` ridiculously small, e.g. `delta=1e-310`.

Comment: @durbachit I'm confused. How did you trigger this error in the first place? what ever workflow that was, trim it down to MCVE based on the principles in the references we've provided .

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you, this was indeed the problem! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. One datafile had the `delta=0`. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear it is fixed.  But when I use `delta=0` with a simple example, I get `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: So in my case it was probably as you said, very close to but not equal to zero (but only printed `0.` without the `e` notation perhaps due to previously imposed formatting to two significant digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` if `delta` is extremely small (e.g. `delta=1e-310`).  Check your code and data to ensure that the values that you pass for `delta` are reasonable.